# Laurent expansion question $f(z) =$ $\frac{1}{(z-4)(z+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been given $f(z) =$ $\frac{1}{(z-4)(z+1)}$. valid in the annulus $1<|z|<4$.
I broke it up into partial fractions to get $f(z)$ = $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{(z-4)}$ $-$ $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{(z+1)}$.
How do I find the Laurent expansion of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's begin with the first term. We have

$$\frac{1}{z-4}=\frac{1}{-4\cdot (-\frac{z}{4}+1)}=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{4}}=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac z4\right)^k,$$
which converges, iff $\left|\frac z4\right|<1$ or equivalently $|z|<4$.

Now continue with the second term. We get
$$\frac{1}{z+1}=\frac{1}{z(1+\frac 1z)}=\frac1z\cdot \frac {1}{1-\left(-\frac 1z\right)}=\frac 1z\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac1z\right)^k,$$
which converges, iff $\left|-\frac 1z\right|<1$ or equivalently $|z|>1$.

Hence for $z$ with $1<|z|<4$ it yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{z-4}-\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{z+1}&=\frac 14\cdot\left(-\frac 14\right)\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac z4\right)^k-\frac 14\cdot \frac 1z\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac1z\right)^k.
\end{align*}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Is there anything to continue? Isn't that just the answer?